# Perl socket, HP comware router

Tags: perl, sockets

I'm trying to create a script in Perl that does the following

On a Windows 2008 R2 server, connects to a local OpenWRT router.
Send some commands to the router and save the output (interface brief)on a varaible 
Edit the content of the variable (to keep the IP only)
Send the variable again to the router withinin another command

I created a socket but i dont seem to get any luck sending commands to the router. I'm not even sure if I'm logging in.

Here is my code:

```
use IO::Socket;
use strinct;
use warnings;

$iaddr = gethostbyname("192.168.1.237");


$ssh_port = 22;
$sin = sockaddr_in($ssh_port, $iaddr);
socket(DEV, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
connect(DEV, $sin) || die "Can't connect to EN4000: $!\n";

print DEV "user\n";     
print DEV "password\n";

print DEV "echo test >> /etc/config/networkTest \n";
```

I run it, check the file /etc/config/networkTest but no modification is made

Comment: "strict" and "warnings" come strongly recommended. As does checking you have the right port number. Telnet is 23. ssh is 22. But using Net::Telnet might be wise.

Comment: Added strict and warnings and renamed the variable to SSH_port, as expected problem persists and no error messages/warnings are displayed

Comment: You can't simply echo text to an ssh port.  It's not nearly so simple. And if you turn on strict and warnings,  you then need to fix your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Net::SSH::W32Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~scotts/Net-SSH-W32Perl-0.05/lib/Net/SSH/W32Perl.pm)

Here's a quick example;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::W32Perl;

my $host='example.com';
my $user='john';
my $pass="pass";

# Connect
my $ssh = Net::SSH::W32Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login($user, $pass);

# Run command
my $cmd = q(echo test >> /etc/config/networkTest);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! I just got one question, What's the "q" before (echo test >> ....) for?

And got any ideas in how I can save the terminals output in a variable? Ex: 
    $my variable = cat networkTest;

Comment: q() - is an alternative way to quote strings, I prefer to use it instead of quotes for command stings as it avoids unnecessary escaping of actual quote characters - a little redundant in this example I admit :)

Comment: The variable `$stdout` should have basic output from the command. To stream real time output look at [$ssh->register_handler](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.38/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm#$ssh->register_handler($packet_type,_$subref_[,_@args_]))

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I encounter the explanation for q() in another site. I was also was able to get the terminal output using my($var)=$ssh->cmd($cmd); iand was able to verifie this printing the value of $var